# Why Facebook Developer ROBOT SUPPORT not verifying my individual identity?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Dear Facebook **(individual) Developers** ,

**Anyone has an issue with verifying individual identity?**

I have a request in Facebook developer, asking me to verify my identity still not accepting my documants and I they open an automatic case **Handled by Robot not human being** my case number is #355130875274022 . Facebook Chatbot (Autoresponse) Support suck and useless it keeps responding and rejecting with the same details over and over without any details even though I provided more than what they ask in each time still they send me the same message  .

Even that I have sent the same long message that you'll find below still sending me the same message. (That's where I understood that it is a Chatbot  Support not actual human being)

**How Can I Talk to human being from Facebook?**

I've even create a post in facebook community even though there is no section for developers topic:

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=357846915002418&added&rdrhc

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Below is My message to Facebook Support that they still response to me as the pictures above**

---

It seems like I don't get your request clearly.
Please, it's been long conversation on the same topic and I have done the same thing you asked repeatedly the same thing over and over again.

please don't copy and paste your support answers.

I am struggling here and need your CLEAR SUPPORT to use your facebook service on my game to login and play with friends

You requested changing my Facebook Account Name to be be My Personal Name As My ID (Passport or Driving License ... etc) using the link below

Changing Facebook Account Name: **(In Original Post I provided an screenshot of my account setting showing the name as Passport from the account + my Picture)**

https://www.facebook.com/help/173909489329079?ref=cr

ID Types: **(In Original Post I provided an attachment of my passport, Driving License, University Degree certificate, Phone Bill, Bank statement )**

https://www.facebook.com/help/159096464162185?ref=cr

*** My Response To That (OVER AND OVER):**

I have Updated my Facebook Account name as My Passport Name Even My Email Sender Name Changed it as my Name in Passport (Please Find Attachment for prove from my Account Settings and my passport copy)

---

Now Of course No one on Earth who is using Facebook as Individual developer even if not for facebook NO ONE ON EARTH WILL EVER CREATE AN APP OR GAME WITH HIS FULL NAME AS HIS PASSPORT

UNLESS YOU (FACEBOOK) WANTS MENT FOR INDIVIDUAL DEVELOPER TO HAVE APPS AS HIS PASSPORT NAME, THEN I'LL STOP DEALING WITH YOU

I am making a game called (Geniuses Battle) where I would like to use Facebook services for login and Play with friends which is allowed for Individual developer as shown here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/#individual-verification

Unless you are using chatbot for the support,
If you are HUMAN Typing now, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE , consider me as Child user who don't understand your repeated answer , Don't Repeat your answer.

Explain to me what am I missing, Guide me step by step till I success Call me or I call you, Contact me on Messenger calls until I complete the process.

I am unable to go through the process to create a legal business it cost a lot (PLUS YOU OVER VERIFYING FOR INDIVIDUAL)

Regards,

Comment: First of all, you are in completely the wrong place here with this. No one here can help you with this issue, you need to keep working with Facebook via the channel they provide for this.

Comment: Secondly of all, it is a _requirement_ that you develop your apps using your personal account, that bears your actual name. If you don’t like that, then go develop on a different platform … Not even sure what your actual issue with this is though – none of your app users will ever see that this app is tied to your personal profile to begin with. So, why the exaggerated panic AND SHOUTING to begin with …?

Comment: @misorude Have you read my topic clearly  before you comment and vote down? Regarding your (Frist of all) I am clearly asking from the beginning if someone faced similar problem and how they handle it also how can I speak to human being in Facebook? So if you know the Facebook channel they provided with human being answering please let me know

Comment: @misorude Regarding your (Secondly of all), it is very clear that you didn't read my topic. I have provided everything they need I even use my name in passport in my Facebook account even the username (check the new uploaded picture).  I have nothing left to do to prove that it is me and this is my account and I am individual developer. STILL THE ROBOT SUPPORT asking me for changes and requests that I already provided. If you have any idea how to verify my account so I can publish my app, please let me know.